# Dynamic formula

Tags: formula, dynamic

I'm trying to make a formula that dynamically gets a value from a field. By this I mean that I have defined a field, I want data from, in custom settings, and I want the formula to get the value of that field.

Example formula:

```
$Organization.Address
```

which returns the value of the address field of the organization

So why doesn't something like the following work? Is there a way I can get this to work so that I am getting whatever value is in the field defined by the custom settings:

```
 Linked_Product__r.( $Setup.Settings__c.Cost_Field__c )
 /* note that $Setup.Settings__c.Cost_Field__c would return something along the lines of "Field__c" */
```

> Error: Unknown function Linked_Product__r.. Check spelling.

If I am unclear please inform me, I will try to clarify more or provide more code.

Update Edit:

```
{!repricing.Linked_Product__r.[$Setup.Settings__c.Cost_Field__c]}
```

> Save error: Invalid field for sObject Product__c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Visualforce using a formula using the dynamic field notation:

```
someRecord.Linked_Product__r[$Setup.Settings__c.Cost_Field__c]
```

However, you can't do this other types of formulas, including validation rules, formula fields, and workflow rules. It's simply not supported.

Comment: I've implemented this in my visualforce page, however am still having some issues.  I am using the code in the edit above, and am getting the error in the edit above. Any ideas? Note that the field in the settings does exist on the Linked Product object.  If I have to, I'll just make a variable in the controller, but I'd prefer to not do that.

Comment: @KonnorMcDowell "Field was not queried error"? Dynamic fields won't be queried automatically, which can cause problems. You'll still need to include a hard reference to the field in the page somewhere or modify the controller to query all fields that might be used.